# XDocument Reading XML file with Root element having namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml

I am having some trouble parsing an XML file with the root node having multiple namespaces. I want to get a list of nodes 'object' with type string containing 'UserControlLibrary' :
XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net 
http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">

<!-- master pages -->
<object type="RLN.Site, RLN">
    <property name="ContainerBLL" ref="ContainerBLL"></property>
    <property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL"></property>
    <property name="TestsBLL" ref="TestsBLL"></property>
<property name="GuidBLL" ref="GuidBLL"></property>
</object>

<object type="RLN.UserControlLibrary.topleveladmin, RLN.UserControlLibrary">
    <property name="ContainerBLL" ref="ContainerBLL"></property>
    <property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL"></property>
    <property name="GuidBLL" ref="GuidBLL"></property>
</object>



<object type="RLN.UserControlLibrary.topleveladminfloat, RLN.UserControlLibrary">
    <property name="ContainerBLL" ref="ContainerBLL"></property>
    <property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL"></property>
</object>
</objects>
```

I have tried:

```
  XDocument webXMLResource = XDocument.Load(@"../../../../Web.xml");
  IEnumerable<XElement> values = webXMLResource.Descendants("object");
```

with no results being returned.

Answer (score 13):

One more trick with namespaces - you can use [XElement.GetDefaultNamespace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace.aspx) to get default namespace of root element. Then use this default namespace for querying:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var objects = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "object");
```

Comment: It doesn't work when an intermediate node bears additional namespace. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alireza yes, exactly. In that case objects will not be in default namespace of root element

Answer (score 5):

When you call `Decendants` with a `XName` parameter the `XName`'s`NameSpace` (which happened to be empty) is actually incorporated into the `Name` in addition to `LocalName`. So you can query just by`LocalName`

```
p.Descendants().Where(p=>p.Name.LocalName == "object")
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the namespace:

```
var ns = new XNamespace("http://www.springframework.net");
IEnumerable<XElement> values = webXMLResource.Descendants(ns + "object");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using decedent than you have to add name space like below

```
 XDocument webXMLResource = XDocument.Load(@"../../../../Web.xml");
 XNamespace _XNamesapce = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
 IEnumerable<XElement> values = from ele in webXMLResource .Descendants(_XNamesapce + "object")
                                select ele;
```

Hope it will work for you