# XML read error (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

First off this is not a duplicate question, I have searched and searched and cannot find what I am looking for.

Heres my problem, I am trying to read through an XML document and store the values in a in labels on my winforms app, I have managed to do this in the same app but this one just isn't working...

Heres the XML document

```
<Root>
  <productinfo>
    <id>7698011</id>
    <productinfo>WP Online Contract</productinfo>
    <url>LINK_URL_REMOVED</url>
    <user>futuredesigngrp</user>
    <thumbnail>LINK_URL_REMOVED</thumbnail>
    <sales>73</sales>
    <rating>5</rating>
    <rating_decimal>5.00</rating_decimal>
    <cost>16.00</cost>
    <uploaded_on>Tue May 13 16:13:43 +1000 2014</uploaded_on>
    <last_update>Sun Jun 29 18:58:15 +1000 2014</last_update>
    <tags>client, contract, create, edit, mobile, online, plugin, responsive, sign, sign online, signature, upload, wordpress</tags>
    <category>wordpress/utilities</category>
    <live_preview_url>LINK_URL_REMOVED</live_preview_url>
  </productinfo>
</Root>
```

Here is my code:

```
            productID = Properties.Settings.Default.WorkingID;
            productSite = Properties.Settings.Default.ProductSite;
            this.Text = this.Text + " :: Viewing Product ID #" + Properties.Settings.Default.WorkingID;

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string productDetails = client.DownloadString("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/v3/item:" + productID + ".json");

            XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(productDetails, "Root");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"productDetails_" + productID + ".xml", node.ToString());

            var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"productDetails_" + productID + ".xml");
            fileContents = fileContents.Replace("<item>", "<productinfo>");
            fileContents = fileContents.Replace("</item>", "</productinfo>");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"productDetails_" + productID + ".xml", fileContents);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("productDetails_" + productID + ".xml");

            foreach (var dm in doc.Descendants("productinfo"))
            {
                //label11.Text = dm.Element("id").Value;
                //label12.Text = dm.Element("productinfo").Value;
                label13.Text = dm.Element("category").Value;
                label14.Text = dm.Element("url").Value;
                label15.Text = dm.Element("user").Value;
                label16.Text = dm.Element("sales").Value;
                label17.Text = dm.Element("rating_decimal").Value;
                label18.Text = "$" + dm.Element("cost").Value;
                label19.Text = dm.Element("uploaded_on").Value;
                label20.Text = dm.Element("last_update").Value;
            }
```

However when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What line do you get that error at?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot When I try to read the elements, so it starts on label13.Text = dm.Element("category").Value; and for every other label. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure doc.Descendants("prodcutinfo") has anything in it?

Comment: Check if doc is not null. Rgds

Comment: I bet your XName needs a namespace... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19142879/2101267

Comment: It seems to be yes, I have the same code on another form for a different XML document and it works fine, I simply copy/pasted my old code for simplicity and changed the file name and child elements

Comment: label13 isn't initialized?

Comment: Guys label13 is already on the form, it seemed productinfo was conflicting, I will post the answer in 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reproducible if an XML data does not contains some attributes (for example "category"). I see that your xml-data contains nested "productinfo" tags, thus the expression
`dm.Element("category")` returns `null` and produce an exception when processing nested "productinfo" tags.

You can either skip nested "productinfo" tags processing:

```
foreach(var dm in doc.Descendants("productinfo")) {
    if(!dm.HasElements) return;;
    //...
```

or just remove/rename nested "productinfo" tags, or use the following improvement for access to the XElement.Value property:

```
string category = dm.Element("category").GetValueOrDefault("Uncategorized");
string url = dm.Element("url").GetValueOrDefault();
//...


public static class XElementExtension { 
    // GetValueOrDefault extension for XElement
    public static string GetValueOrDefault(this XElement element, string defaultValue = null) {
        return (element != null) ? element.Value : defaultValue;
    }
}
```